# Claiming my BTG from my BTC private key

Tags: bitcoin-gold

I have a BTC private key, how do I get my BTG? I have tried a few methods and tutorials but none seem to be working.
And beside that, is there any working BTG explorer? All the ones I found seem to be buggy (including btgexp.com) and wont recognize my address.

EDIT: yes I had BTC on this address at the time of the split

EDIT 2: found a working explorer with https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin%20gold

EDIT 3: yes I have transferred all my BTC to another address, and I just want to get rid of my BTG now

Comment: Did you have any bitcoin balance on the adress of which the private key belongs to, on `BTG snapshot block 491407`

Comment: Did you try to use a BTG wallet and import the keys?

Comment: Also, have you transferred the BTC to another wallet? I strongly recommend this before importing the keys to avoid any of the scams that seem to be abundant in connection to Bitcoin Gold.

Comment: @DanielR, are you talking about Bitcoin Gold's Core Wallet?  It doesn't seem to support importing of private keys at the moment.  Referring to https://bitcoingold.org/downloads/

Comment: If you have an iOS device, you can follow these instructions which I discovered myself: https://medium.com/@SimonEast/how-to-sweep-bitcoin-gold-btg-from-a-paper-wallet-using-ios-86010fa208de

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK there's one good wallet other than the reference client that can import the private key and make a transaction.

That's Coinomi, it can import the private key and does support BTG.

(When I wanted to dump and sell my BTG, Coinomi was great, although I needed to use the Android emulator Genymotion [because I don't have an android device])

Comment: Most of the tutorials I have found googling are using Coinomi and this did not work for me.
I have moved my BTC from the address and only have BTG left, if I try sweeping the private key from Coinomi, I keep getting the message "The private key does not contain any funds".

Comment: But it does contain BTG! I can see it on https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin%20gold/address/

Comment: Alleluia, this finally worked!!!

Comment: @Oliver It was what I expected. You're welcome! <sub><sub><sub><sub>That green button next to my answer, please.</sub></sub></sub></sub>

Answer (score -4):

Solution:

First, confirm your BTG balance on https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin%20gold/address/

1. go to https://www.bitaddress.org "Wallet Details"
2. (optional) Download the site to use it locally offline, check the github code to confirm it does not do anything harmful
3. put your BTC private key and press View Details
4. Install Coinomi
5. Create a new wallet and add BTG, then choose Sweep Wallet
6. Swipe the QR Code "Private Key WIF 51 characters base58, starts with
   a '5'

DONE!!!

Always try first with a low value address, dont trust anyone when playing with private keys

EDIT 1: added step BTG explorer
EDIT 2: changed step 2 (optional)

Comment: To check the BTCG balance, I can use my BTC public key?

Comment: What date did the airdrop happen on?

Comment: @levi The airdrop happened on 1 Aug. No, you can't use the BTC public key, but the private keys are the same. Import your private keys to Coinomi and it'll show you your balance and addresses.

Comment: Beware, you should not upload your private key to anywhere. Never!

Comment: NEVER EVER give your private keys to some random site found on internet!