# How to claim BTG from an Electrum wallet?

Tags: electrum, bitcoin-gold

Claiming BTG after the Fork did not work

I have tried :
using Coinomi wallet,[this way](https://coinomi.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/29000016909-i-didn-t-have-btc-in-coinomi-at-the-time-of-the-snapshot-how-do-i-claim-btg-).

I could not locate the address holding eligible for BTG value.
All addresses i tried was contained no fund.
In the history tab i could not spot the addresses details.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is that BTG uses a different address format than BTC? This means that the addresses you held coins in before the fork need to be translated to BTG first?

Answer (score 3):

Try this: [Claiming my BTG from my BTC private key](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/63088/claiming-my-btg-from-my-btc-private-key/63227#63227)
Worked for me

To know where your BTG are use this explorer: https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin%20gold/

Comment: I have already used this site. It was very useful. But still there all of the pricate codes leads to the same error: The privte key does not contain any fund.

Comment: When you are on https://www.bitaddress.org, try sweeping the QR code private key on the left, if it does not work try the one on the right

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution!

After browsing through the addresses in the Electrum wallet, I looked for all addresses that have non-zero Tx value. I found the one holding BTG in the last address of the list located in Addresses>change>Used , it was the last one of them. And indeed that is the one showing up in the history of the last transaction of my wallet , in its detail's input tab.

View private key in that address , and then scanning from Coinomi, using "Sweet wallet got me the last amount before the fork of my wallet in BTG

Comment: I had the same problem. The default filter in the addresses tab is 'receiving'. None of those, including the non-zero-transaction ones, had any Bitcoin Gold. But changing the filter dropdown to 'change', and then checking each of those non-zero addresses (using https://bitinfocharts.com/bitcoin%20gold/ ), worked. Two of the addresses between them had the number of BTG that I was expecting. Thanks!

Comment: I assume now it wouldn't be worth?  Even if I had 1 BTC before the split?

Answer (score -2):

bitaddress.org will not accept electrum private keys, saying invalid key version 133 not supported.

electrum only gives one private key per address.

"This is independent of the wallet you are using, and you should be able to export it, all wallets allow it" - don't think electrum does this. at least I cannot find a way.

Comment: When I say "private key" I dont mean "electrum's private key", I mean the private key associated with your Bitcoin address. This is independent of the wallet you are using, and you should be able to export it, all wallets allow it (I dont know electrum so I cannot help on this one)

Comment: electrum provides only one private key per address, nothing independent as you say

Comment: Obviously there is one and only one private key per address, and yes the private key is wallet independent, otherwise you are not talking about private key but something else